# Update Redis Token data at Run Time Spring Boot & OAuth2 Security

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-security-oauth2

I want to update the spring security session that is stored in redis server along with token generated by spring oauth2. 
 Without Redis or Using InMemoryToken Store i am able to update the session value at run time associated with spring oauth2.0 token.
  But when trying to update the same spring security session value at run time using redis then spring sessionvalue is updated but when trying to access the session value via token i am not getting updated value